# Seg Fault When using If statments in a loop

Tags: c

I am trying to parse through a file, and store the results using a struct, but I keep getting a segmetaion error and I cant seem to figure out why.

```
 while (token ! = NULL)
    {
        token =strtok(NULL, " ");

        if (token[0] == 'd')
        {  
           if (token[1] == 'e')
            {
               room -> eastD = atoi(&token[2]);

               printf("%d",room->eastD);
            }
         }
    }
```

Comment: What if `strtok` returns `NULL`? What does the expression `token[0] == 'd'` do then?

Comment: after `token =strtok(NULL, " ");`, check `if(token)`

Comment: Read the [strtok documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

Comment: @MichaelWalz, I just read it, and it convinced me never to use the function. What kind of godawful design is that?

Comment: I must admit that the design of `strtok` is not very good but it's a standard function of the c library.

Comment: `! =` is invalid syntax, you may write those two separately like that. This probably wouldn't cause an access violation though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about check following token is NULL.

```
 token =strtok(NULL, " ");
```

You should also NULL check it.

```
if(token != NULL)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's because token is NULL and then you try and dereference it.  You're doing your loop wrong.

```
token = strtok( input_str, " " );
while( token != NULL )
{
    if ( strlen( token ) > 2 )
    {
        if ( token[0] == 'd' )
        {  
            if ( token[1] == 'e' )
            {
                room->eastD = atoi( &token[2] );
                printf( "%d", room->eastD );
            }
        }
    }
    token = strtok( NULL, " " );
}
```